# Rules to avoid repeated data on Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I need to create a validation rule in firebase to don't have repeated data like a primary key in a relational DB. Here is the code I was trying:

```
"roles": {
        ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        "$rol_id": {
          ".write": "auth.uid != null",
          ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['description', 'state'])",
          "description": {
            ".validate": "newData.isString() && 
            newData.val().matches(/[A-Za-z]$/i) && 
            root.child('roles').child('$rol_id').child('description').val() != 
            root.child('roles').child('$rol_id').child('description').exists()" 
          },
          "state": {
            ".validate":"newData.isBoolean()"
          }
        }
    },
```

The problem is that I can't enter in `$rol_id` unless i give it a constant value but i need it to evaluate in each object.

This is the structure from roles in firebase:

```
"roles" : {
    "-KMohJaG6djjeBiq3oiV" : {
      "creationDate" : 1468689365795,
      "description" : "administrador",
      "id" : "-KMohJaG6djjeBiq3oiV",
      "permissions" : {
        "inputs" : true,
        "kardex" : true,
        "outputs" : true,
        "persons" : true,
        "product" : false,
        "rol" : true,
        "sales" : true,
        "supplier" : true,
        "user" : true
      },
      "state" : true
    },
}
```

Comment: Try `root.child('roles').child($rol_id)`, so without the quotes around `$rol_id`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it didn't work, i still can push repeated data